# Transactional methods in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have been working in Grails earlier and in Grails, same as Spring, service methods are transactional by default, we can change it through annotations if we want, but now I am working in ASP.net and I want to know if there is something similar to that.
Or we must explicitly open transaction and close it at the end of each method. I am using entity framework...

Comment: This isn't really a fit for StackOverflow, it really belongs as a question on Programmers StackExchange.  Having said that, there are many links available on the Internet about using transactions with EF.

Comment: @LSU.Net when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty good article on transactions in EF
[Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Transactions; 

namespace TransactionsExamples 
{ 
    class TransactionsExample 
    { 
        static void StartOwnTransactionWithinContext() 
        { 
            using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
            { 
                using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                { 
                    try 
                    { 
                        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
                            @"UPDATE Blogs SET Rating = 5" + 
                                " WHERE Name LIKE '%Entity Framework%'" 
                            ); 

                        var query = context.Posts.Where(p => p.Blog.Rating >= 5); 
                        foreach (var post in query) 
                        { 
                            post.Title += "[Cool Blog]"; 
                        } 

                        context.SaveChanges(); 

                        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception) 
                    { 
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With EntityFramework, all of your pending data storage operations will happen within a single unit of work (transaction) when you invoke `SaveChanges` (or `SaveChangesAsync`) on the `DbContext` instance.

If you want to split up the work into multiple transactions, you would want to invoke `SaveChanges` (or the async equivalent) each time you want to commit a transaction.

Comment: If I have something like this: Update, Select, Update, SaveChanges it is transactional, but in this case Select wont take into consideration changes made in first Update because Select hits the database, and changes in Update are not saved to DB. If I do Update, SaveChanges, Select, Update, SaveChanges then it is not transactional, because if second Update throws exception the first one wont be rollbacked. So I am not sure if I can use only SaveChanges to simulate transactions...